# Multiple gridspec layout in a single plot

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

Using GridSpec to make subplots, I would like to have different hspace or wspace all along my grid. I read somewhere that the easiest would be to create different grids for a single plot, such that I could have different values for my parameters hspace and wspace.

However, the only case when I can stack different grids is by pasting the example given in the doc : https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout

Could someone explain why in the code bellow, only the last grid is displayed ? The goal is only to stack two grids vertically.

```
gs_top = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs_top[0:2, 0:2])
#ax2 = plt.subplot(gs_top[0:2, 1])

gs_bottom = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2)

ax3 = plt.subplot(gs_bottom[0, 0])
ax4 = plt.subplot(gs_bottom[0, 1])
ax5 = plt.subplot(gs_bottom[1, 0:2])
```

I really don't understand how to control the "grid stacking" ...
In the example of the doc, how does python knows that grid are stacked horizontally and not vertically ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [the example](https://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#adjust-gridspec-layout) the first grid is on the left side of the plot, because its subplot parameters are set so

```
gs1.update(left=0.05, right=0.48)
```

It starts at 5% of the figure width and ends at 48% from the figure width. 
The second grid,

```
gs2.update(left=0.55, right=0.98)
```

starts at 55% and ends at 98%. 100% would be the right figure edge.

Instead of `left` and `right` you may use `bottom` and `top` for the vertical positioning.